# App opens with Rear Facing Camera launched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, launch

What's the best method of having the rear facing camera run when the app successfully launches?

I'd like my app to open with a modal view controller first that way the user can dismiss the camera if they do not wish to take a photo at that time.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have figured this out... It's a lot easier than I was making it!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.UIPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.UIPicker.delegate = self;
    self.UIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self launchCamera];
}

- (void)launchCamera
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
    {
        self.UIPicker.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        [self presentViewController:self.UIPicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self.UIPicker.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        [self presentViewController:self.UIPicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

// image picker delegate code here
```

Another question though:

I am using a custom overlay, but the native "shutter" graphic still shows. How can this be removed or hidden?

Thanks!

Comment: if my answer helped you to achieve your target then please accept it.

Comment: I'm afraid it did not. The camera does not launch when the app launches with the code provided. Could you expand on it a little more?

Comment: this condition must work as i am also using this to open my front camera in many apps...i think you're doing something wrong way please provide the code of your camera opening so that i can take a look at it.

Comment: To confirm, where should this run at? ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear? The camera opens fine (via button tap or action sheet), but I want it running as soon as the app launches, such as Snapchat or Clipchat

Comment: i don't think it's possible to hide or remove the native shutter graphics because as per my understanding the custom overlay comes after your camera starts but the shutter graphics is before your camera starts so that might be a default way/procedure for camera i might be wrong but this is what i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this below condition

```
if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) 
{
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
}
else 
{
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
}
```